# Can anyone help me identify this Chinese signs please?

Tags: character-identification, old-chinese

My grandfather was in China in the early 20th century.
In family heirlooms, there was a box with such a sign in the upper corner. Probably the signature of whoever made this box.

Can anyone help me with what it means?

[image]

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

the picture needs to be turned upside-down

the text is “周宜”

[image]

Comment: Ohhh   Thank you very much ! :)